# how to use For loop to get a certain value in a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to get certain values from lists inside a dictionary and create a new variable for those values using for loop in Python.

```py
sales = {'c1': [30.2, "lily"], 'c2': [31.3, "sam"], 'c3': [28.2, 'peter'], 'c4': [28.5, 'chan']}
```

expected output:
`sales_sum = [30.2, 31.3, 28.2, 28.5]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sales_sum = [x[0] for x in sales.values()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [28]: sales = {'c1': [30.2, "lily"], 'c2': [31.3, "sam"], 'c3': [28.2, 'peter'], 'c4': [28.5, 'chan']}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [29]: next(zip(*sales.values()))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[29]: (30.2, 31.3, 28.2, 28.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
python_sales = {'c1': [30.2, "lily"], 'c2': [31.3, "sam"], 'c3': [28.2, 'peter'], 'c4': [28.5, 'chan']}
sales_sum=[]
for sale in python_sales.keys():
    sales_sum.append(python_sales[sale][0])
```

does the trick?
(although all other answers here are probably prettier)

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension answers are nice, but if u want more readable:

```
for v in sales.values():
    sales_sum.append(v[0])
```